# How to debug malloc/memleaks in FreeBSD

Tags: c, memory-management, freebsd

I have come across this article:
http://keramida.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/extracting-useful-info-from-freebsd-malloc-tracing/

It seemes like that script referenced in the article is out of date, and the link in the first comment is 404.

Valgrind doesnt seem to be working for me on FreeBSD because of some system calls and an error about implementing them myself which I have no interest in doing.

Is there anything like what this script says it can do to track malloc/free?

Thanks

Comment: Use the internet archive: http://archive.org/web/web.php.

Comment: Internet archive had the first version of that guys script, but not the second =(

Comment: You could try emailing the guy... keramida at FreeBSD.org

Answer (score 1):

The [devel/valgrind](http://freshports.org/devel/valgrind) port was upgraded recently and may fulfill your needs now.

But FreeBSD's malloc-implementation (also known as phk-malloc) has some built-in functionality too. Read the [malloc(3)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=malloc&sektion=3) man-page for details -- the "TUNING" section contains information useful for developers as well.

Comment: I will have to check it out. I kind of forgot about this call, but I ended up fixing valgrind myself so I will compare to see what was done in the port.

Comment: @Mikhail FreeBSD uses [jemalloc](http://jemalloc.net/) (not phk-malloc) since 2005

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you could enable [mtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mtrace) in your program, but it is a code change.

On OpenBSD, you could try the malloc stats.

Google's leak checker might also be worth a look, and unlike mtrace you may be able to use LD_PRELOAD to avoid recompilation.

Comment: I can't really port this code to Linux. It requires some FreeBSD specific pieces. I had tried to get valgrind up and going, but all I could get from it were some errors about unhandled syscalls

Answer (score 0):

You could try instrumenting (linking) your code with the `devel/ElectricFence` port. As long as your code doesn't allocate zillions of small bites, this should help you find accesses past allocated memory. If you are just checking for leaks, ElectricFence is maybe not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I checked into it, and you're right, for invalid accessses it might be alright, but doesnt seem to be good for leak detection.